# Turn.js Magazines Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, turnjs

I have a problem with Turn.js Magazines module in drupal (https://www.drupal.org/project/turnjs_magazines).

I have installed all the depencdenies. When i create a new content turn.js Magazine, I can upload the .pdf file, and I can save the node successfully, but there is no PDF rendering. I have module pdf_to_imagefield, but nothing happens.

Any idea why?

Comment: Check php dependencies , or librairies ?

Comment: We tried on colleagues PC and it works fine.
We compared the installed PHP dependencies and extensions, and there is no difference

Comment: Do you have imagemagik configured ?

Comment: Yes. Problem solved. I didn't have Ghostscript.